# Unable to get pure json from a url

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to get the response from a url so that I can make use of it later. The response I wish to get is json. However, what I get instead is more like json:

```
{"DISPLAY":{"ADA":{"EUR":{"PRICE":"€ 0.07575","SPRICE":"€ 0.08","CHANGE24HOUR":"€ -0.011","CHANGEPCT24HOUR":"-12.58","CLOSED":"€ 0.08","DAY":-12.290825158684369,"HIGH24HOUR":"€ 0.087","LOW24HOUR":"€ 0.072","MKTCAP":"€ 1963975593.25","MKTCAP_ROUND":"€ 1.96 B","MONTH":27.26481127968117,"OPEN24HOUR":"€ 0.08665","SUPPLY":"ADA 25.93 B","TIMESTAMP":1559305128,"VOLUME24HOUR":"ADA 22.74 M","VOLUME24HOURTO":"€  1.78 M","WEEK":9.685520068120473,"DATA_PROVIDER":2}
```

I've written so far:

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://ticker.cointelegraph.com/tickers'

res = requests.get(url)
print(res.text)

#the following line throws an error
print(json.loads(res.text))
```

Using `json.loads()`, I get the following error:

```
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 14796 (char 14795)
```

***How can I fetch pure json content from that url?***

Comment: The json is invalid. In line 682 something went wrong.  --> "DAY": +Inf,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the content of `res.text`, or the content of page `https://ticker.cointelegraph.com/tickers`, there is a `+Inf` in the string which causes the error, perhaps replacing it with a parsable object, e.g the string `+Inf` or number `0`

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://ticker.cointelegraph.com/tickers'

res = requests.get(url)

#Replaced the +Inf with +Inf string
json_obj = json.loads(res.text.replace('+Inf','"+Inf'))

#Or replace the +Inf with 0 string                  
#json_obj = json.loads(res.text.replace('+Inf','0'))
```

Then `json_obj` will have your expected output